# Scroll down page in the web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a Webbrowser in my windows form and I want it to automatically scroll down the page. Now I do this

```
this.webBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, int.MaxValue);
```

but when I start my application, webBrowser don't scrolls. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work!!!)))

```
class KeyHandle
{
    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

    public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0);
    }
}
```

Call method:

```
KeyHandle.SendKey(this.webBrowser.Handle, Keys.PageDown);
```

Comment: doesn't work, webbrowser scroll bars don't move neither the page

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
function top() {
    document.getElementById( 'top' ).scrollIntoView();    
};

function bottom() {
    document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
    window.setTimeout( function () { top(); }, 2000 );
};

bottom();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know javascript. I have to do this in my c# application.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myInterval = false;
    myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 2000);

    function AutoScroll() {
        var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        iScroll = iScroll + 500;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: iScroll
        }, 1000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (iScroll == 0) {
            myInterval = setInterval(AutoScroll, 2000);
        }
        if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    });
});
```